# Interceptor in mixed config: SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and annotated controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an "old" Spring web project which I try to upgrade progressively, meaning I need to make things work the old and the new way at the same time. For instance I have an interceptor and the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping declared this way:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="acessControlInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="page1.do">page1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="acessControlInterceptor" class="org.foo.AccessControlInterceptor">
    <property name="someBO" ref="org.foo.bo.ISomeBO"/>  
</bean>
```

I started integrating controllers with the @Controller and @RequestMapping("/page2.do") annotations, meaning I don't add the urls to SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, and of course I added the mvc:annotation-driven and context:component-scan stuff. That works, old and new pages get along, but i realized my interceptor is not called for those new controllers. So I added that to my config:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="acessControlInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Which works, I mean the interceptor is "called"... but the property "someBO" is always null now!
Here is the interceptor (simplified):

```
public class AccessControlInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private ISomeBO someBO;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse, Object handler) throws Exception {
        ...
        // throws a null pointer exception on someBO
    }

    public ISomeBO getSomeBO() {
        return someBO;
    }

    public void setSomeBO(ISomeBO pSomeBO) {
        someBO = pSomeBO;
    }
}
```

How come now the attributes (because actually I have many) of my interceptors are not set anymore?

Thanks!

**EDIT:
So I cleaned up and restarted from scratch and now it works... Thanks to all of you who "wasted" time reading and answering! I hope maybe my question will at least help guys looking for this kind of config ;-)**

Comment: was this attribute set before? I don't see any reason for it not to work now if it was already working

Comment: Just to confirm remove the `mvc:interceptors` settings and try again to see whether it is set

Answer (score 0):

The reference you have provided for BO is wrong.

```
<property name="someBO" ref="org.foo.bo.ISomeBO"/>
```

In reference you have given the full qualified name of BO class. There should be bean name of the BO class.

Try changing that. I think that will resolve your problem.

Comment: I didn't put the whole config ;-) The bean "org.foo.bo.ISomeBO" is declared in another config file. Anyway it used to work...